# Tkinter Frame not resized when a widget appears

Tags: python, tkinter, resize

I'm playing around a piece of code. Intended behavior is when the button is pressed, button2 should be shown and window should be enlarged (downwards) to contain the new button2, too. The grid layout is 2 rows [0:1] and 1 column. Column width is resized and OK but rows[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgUDQ.png) height is not changed.
This is before pressing Button 'Teszt':

[image: This is before pressing Button 'Teszt']

After pressing Button 'Text', the width changes (due to button2 "width": 20 property); height not:
[image: After pressing Button 'Text', the width changes; height not]

The button is there, but hidden:

[image: The button is there, but hidden:]

```
from Tkinter import *

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tesztText = ""
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.top = self.winfo_toplevel()

        self.button = Button(self.top, {"text": "Teszt", "command": self.teszt_get, })
        self.button.grid({"sticky": S + N + E + W, "row":0, "column": 0, })

        self.button2 = Button(self.top, {"text": "Teszt2", "width": 20})

    def teszt_get(self):
        self.button2.grid({"sticky": S + N + E + W, "row": 1, "column": 0})

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: My mistake, later I changed the Treeview to another button. Pics added

Comment: So your window doesn't resize even though there is a new button when you manually resize it with mouse, correct?

Comment: When I use the code above, after pressing the only button it goes from 1st image to 3rd image you've provided. I never experience the 2nd image(unless perhaps momentarily while GUI update process is still in progress but that's a tiny little time).

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me. It starts out small, when I click the button it grows in both width and height as the second button is added.

Comment: Thanks, then this might be an OS (Kubuntu) bug, I'll check it on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously a Kubuntu(Wily)/Python(2.7.10) bug, worked on Win 10/Python(2.7.13).